# Filling the table of numbers

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Given the following table:

[image]

I have already found the first 4 digits: $6\cdot 3 =  18, \ \ 6\cdot 2=12$ and therefore, the first 4 digits are $1812$. I cannot determine how to continue... Any help is appreciated.

This table came from my sister's math homework.

Comment: 'Your sister's math homework' - could you be more specific please? E.g. what book?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's just a local school-book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think answer will be

> $82$ ( for last digit)

Because

> Let three number given denote a,b & c then using this formula (a * b)+ (a * c) - c  
>  For first row  : a = 3 , b = 5 , c = 6 
>  (3 * 5) + (3 * 6) - 6 
>  = 15 + 18 - 6 = 27 (reverse) = $72$ 
>  Second row : (5 * 5) + (5 * 6) - 6 = 49 (reverse) = $94$
>  Third row : ( 5 * 6 ) +( 5 * 7) - 7 = 58 (reverse) = $85$ 
>  Fourth row : (6 * 3) + (6 * 2) - 2 = 28 ( reverse) = $82$